# How to select rows based on iteration on previous rows until a condition is met?

Tags: r

I have a dataset of two columns: one is event type and the other one is time (s).

I would like first create a column 'trial_number' based on each occurrence of the event 'tr_start'. From the first occurrence of 'tr_start', to the second occurrence of 'trial_number' should be equal to 1. From the second to the third should be 2, and so on.

Secondly, I would like to select only the 10s following the trial start ('tr_start').

```
time<- c(92, 96, 97, 100, 103, 104, 106, 111, 112, 115, 118, 119, 123)
event<- c('tr_start', 'on', 'off', 'on', 'off','on', 'off',
'left','on', 'off', 'tr_start', 'left', 'left')
data<- data.frame(time, event)
```

In this example, rows 1 to 10 for the column 'trial_number' should be 1 and for rows 11 to 13 should be 2. 
Secondly, the first 'tr_start' occurs at second (time) 92. For each tr_start I need to keep only the trials that occur in the next 10s. In this case, only rows 1 to 4 (up to second 102) and rows 11 to 13 (10s after each  'tr_start').

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `cumsum`

```
data$group  <- cumsum(data$event == 'tr_start')
```

then we can subset based on the 'group'

```
subset(data, group ==1 & time <= (time[1] + 10))
#   time    event group
#1   92 tr_start     1
#2   96       on     1
#3   97      off     1
#4  100       on     1
```

---

If it needs to be done for each 'group'

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   group_by(group = cumsum(event == "tr_start")) %>%
   filter(time <= (first(time) + 10))
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   group [2]
#   time event    group
#  <dbl> <fct>    <int>
#1    92 tr_start     1
#2    96 on           1
#3    97 off          1
#4   100 on           1
#5   118 tr_start     2
#6   119 left         2
#7   123 left         2
```